# Spring's NamedParameterTemplate - Can't find what dependency it is in

Tags: java, spring

In Spring's reference documentation, the type "NamedParameterTemplate" is referenced as an easy way to do batch updates:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-batch-list

However, I can't find what dependency "NamedParameterTemplate" is part of. Help?

Comment: The [package name](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) is usually an hint

Answer (score 3):

It's part of [Spring JDBC](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.2.RELEASE) library. The class is called `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, it's probably a typo in the docs (in the code snippet, the variable is called `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`).

Comment: I added that dependency and it's not in there:

`compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.2.RELEASE'`

Comment: It's probably a typo in the docs. The class is called `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think NamedParameterTemplate doesn't exist.

Use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate intead.

This is de API Doc

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html

And you can see that NamedParameterJdbcTemplate doesn't extend or implement NamedParameterTemplate